# Why is an arraylist that was reversed using Collections.reverse() compared to its original arraylist giving me true?

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a palindrome using java's arraylist, and though my logic makes sense the output doesn't. If I use the Collections.reverse method to reverse the arraylist it gives me true for a number that's not a palindrome.

```
        int temp = 123;
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        while(temp!=0){
            
            num.add(temp%10);
            temp=temp/10;
            
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> ognum = num;
        Collections.reverse( ognum);

        if(num.equals(ognum)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Output: true

However if I do this:

```
        int temp = 123;
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        while(temp!=0){
            
            num.add(temp%10);
            temp=temp/10;
            
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> ognum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ognum.add(1);
        ognum.add(2);
        ognum.add(3);

        if(num.equals(ognum)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Output: false

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> ognum = num;` what do you think this does?

Comment: Try printing both `num` and `ognum` after reversing ognum. Especially in the first case. As @FedericoklezCulloca already hinted, you are not creating another list in the first case, just another reference to it.

Comment: `ognum` and `num` are the same list (or better, they point to the same list instance) - BTW you can use `new ArrayList<>(num)` to create a new list with the same content as `num` (a copy) || `return num.equals(ognum)` is more *elegant*, avoiding the un-needed `if` (*if it is true return true else false*)

Comment: Try this instead.  `List<Integer> ognum = new ArrayList<>(num);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the `ArrayList<Integer> ognum = num;` instruction.

Instead of copying the values inside the `ArrayList`, all you're doing is copying the same reference into another variable, thus making them the same thing.

If you're new to OOP, what you're essentially doing is grabbing a box, putting a label "*num*" on it and add some stuff into it. After some time, you grab the very same box and you add a second label, this time "*ognum*". No matter what you do with the content of the box, what is inside the box "*num*" **it will be the same** as the box "*ognum*".
This is how your code should look like:

```
    int temp = 123;
    ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
    while(temp!=0){
            
        num.add(temp%10);
        temp=temp/10;
            
     }
     // Here num will contain the values [3,2,1]
    
     ArrayList<Integer> ognum = new ArrayList<>();
     ognum.addAll(num);
     // Here ognum will contain the values [3,2,1]
     
     Collections.reverse(ognum);
     // Here ognum will contain the values [1,2,3]

     return num.equals(ognum); // [3,2,1] == [1,2,3] ? => false
```